# Adding third party library sqlcipher in ios

Tags: ios, linker

I am trying to integrate SQLCipher in one of my existing project with deployment target 6.0 but since sqlcipher supports 9.0 as its minimum deployment target ,so I changed the deployment target to 9.0 now.
With this I made a change in build setting also,I changed "Build active architecture only" to yes.I tried building the app then.But it shows few errors related to already existing classes.

Error-"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConditionViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".
Valid Architecture- armv7 arm64

I am not able to figure out this error and fix it.Kindly help me to resolve it.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you clean project? or restart Xcode some time it happen

Comment: Many number of times I have done this....even tried cleaning derived data also.